# import of package PyDSTool doesn't work

Tags: python, scipy

I tried to install the library PyDSTool via pip install in windows 7. Installed version PyDSTool == 0.90.2. Before that I installed dependencies numpy and scipy. 
Wwhen I tried to import the module PyDSTool into IDE python, I got error something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyDSTool
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
RuntimeError: SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required
```

I corrected the code in the file (C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool__init__.py", line 77) so that's it

```
if tuple(vernums) < tuple([int(n) for n in "0.5.1".split(".")]):
    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
#if vernums[1] < 5:
#    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
```

because version of scipy = 1.0.0 > 0.5.1
SciPy 1.0.0 released 2017-10-25

The next attempt to import the module gave next exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyDSTool
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from .Events import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .Variable import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Variable.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .FuncSpec import ImpFuncSpec
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\FuncSpec.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .Symbolic import QuantSpec, allmathnames_symbolic
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Symbolic.py", line 178, in <module>
    funcnames = [n for n in allmathnames if hasattr(eval(modlookup[n]+n),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sph_jn'
```

I played with the print function and found out that **scipy.special** dont hava attr **"sph_jn"** and this exception arises when python is trying eval next code

```
funcnames = [n for n in allmathnames if hasattr(eval(modlookup[n]+n), "__call__")]
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: FYI: `sph_jn`, `sph_yn`, etc.,  were [deprecated in SciPy 0.18.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.18.0.html#deprecated-features) and [removed in version 1.0.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes).

Comment: Thank you! After installing on Ubuntu the library based on the version dependency scipy I discovered that PyDSTool depends on the version matplotlib...https://github.com/robclewley/pydstool/blob/master/PyDSTool/matplotlib_import.py

Comment: >>> import PyDSTool

Warning: matplotlib failed to import properly and so is not
  providing a graphing interface

after installing scipy=0.18.0

Answer (score 3):

As [Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) already suggested, replacing the following 2 lines (line 46-47) in `parseUtils.py`

```
'h2vp', 'sph_jn', 'sph_yn', 'sph_jnyn', 'sph_in',
'sph_kn', 'sph_inkn', 'riccati_jn', 'riccati_yn',
```

to

```
'h2vp', 'spherical_jn', 'spherical_yn', 'spherical_in',
'spherical_kn', 'riccati_jn', 'riccati_yn',
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: Have you checked that this simple replacement works?  From the [SciPy 1.0.0 release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes) about these functions: "Be aware that the new functions have different signatures."

Comment: Yes, I also read the release notes and confirmed to work on several examples (ex. PyCont_vanDerPol.py). Why this worked was because `parseUtils.py` is a parser util for python script and it only imports scipy special functions (like sph_jn, lmbda) and just tries to evaluate them as Mykola wrote. Obviously, the PyDSTool does not call sph_jn in their code. The problem occurred only at the above evaluation time.

Comment: After the patch you are offering, the import works well. True, I do not know how to test the work of this library. I installed it by pip util without installing on windows fortran and gcc compilers. Thank you very much for the help! These functions that I have replaced in two lines are not exactly used in integration of ODE systems?

Comment: Simply using 'grep' and 'ag' command to search the word 'sph_jn' etc. in the PyDSTool distribution directory, I could not find the match with given query('sph_jn') except `parseUtils.py` file. This means that these functions will not be called during the realization on PyDSTool (except, when a user write the function 'sph_jn' in their code, it may fail. but that's another story). Also, I confirmed that several example scripts works just as before. The reason why this fix works is already written in my above comment.