# PyDSTool with anaconda not installing properly

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I am trying to install PyDSTool with anaconda2 (conda install PyDSTool), which seems to go well. But when I open spyder and import PyDSTool, it gives me error

```
import PyDSTool


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-a214100b00aa>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyDSTool

  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyDSTool/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")

RuntimeError: SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required
```

I tried to change `parseUtils.py` as per this suggestion: [import of package PyDSTool doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251201/import-of-package-pydstool-doesnt-work)
but still the same error. I certainly have SciPy 1.0 and python 2.7.

Comment: see the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369299/pydstool-do-not-recognize-scipy-version/49381874#49381874

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently. The accepted answer here ([PyDSTool do not recognize SciPy version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369299/pydstool-do-not-recognize-scipy-version/49381874#49381874)) is still effective today at solving this problem.

Basically download PyDSTool from here (https://github.com/tkf/pydstool/tree/tkf) instead of sourceforge.