# PyDSTool do not recognize SciPy version

Tags: python, scipy

I have installed `PyDSTool` package :

```
pip install PyDSTool==0.90.2
```

It return :

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyDSTool==0.90.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyDSTool-0.90.2-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from PyDSTool==0.90.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from PyDSTool==0.90.2)    
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from PyDSTool==0.90.2)
```

It tell me that requirement for `scipy` is already satisfied but in python:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyDSTool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyDSTool-0.90.2-py2.7.egg/PyDSTool/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
RuntimeError: SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required
```

I already try the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251201/import-of-package-pydstool-doesnt-work) and also saw [this unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898350/pydstool-with-anaconda-not-installing-properly) which seems to have a similar problem but using `conda` instead of `pip`.

**EDIT :**

I also try to download package and install with the `setup.py` associated but I still have the same problem

**EDIT 2:**

To solve this problem an other option is to downgrade `scipy` :

```
pip install scipy==0.19.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyDSTool project homepage at sourceforge is down: http://pydstool.sourceforge.net/ points to http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/FrontPage.html that returns "file not found".

The project has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/robclewley/pydstool

There are several issues in line with yours there. The problem is that, currently, the development of SciPy's `integrate` module has broken the calls from PyDSTool.

One solution: use an older version of SciPy. The alternatives are either to find yourself the points of failure or to use the fork here: https://github.com/tkf/pydstool/tree/tkf

Comment: thanks to the last link it's now working : https://github.com/tkf/pydstool/tree/tkf, Merci !

Answer (score 2):

`PyDSTool` has a bug in line 76 of `__init__.py`

The original code is as follows:

```
if vernums[1] < 5:
    raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
```

I have changed the code like this and then the problem was gone:

```
if vernums[1] < 5:
    if vernums[0] == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("SciPy v0.5.1 or above is required")
```

The problem was that the original code didn't check the first version code.